# Count formula based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to Count the number of positive results and negative results based on another column.

What I ideally want but not sure if I can have the formula in one cell or do I need a to calculate the results in another cell before final result. So to break it down this is what I want to achieve. Column Y is "Exit Pips" this will either be negative or positive result. Column W is a value based on Column J which is time based. So what I want as an example is:

If column W (TakeorNot) is GT2 then I want to calculate the % of positive results of all W entries. - Not sure if this is too confusing or not.

So if was to break it down it would be something like this:

If Column W is GT2 then I want to count the number of negative results in Column Y. Then I would also calculate the same but for positive results which then would allow me to calculate the %.

I have tried a CountIFS but I get myself confused. Hope this clear.

I appreciate I should ask a second question but how do I upload the spreadsheet rather than a screenshot for reference?

[This is current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qridV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and for proper understanding reload the SCREEN SHOT must show at least Column Name,,, then I'll suggest you a perfect solution!!

Answer (score 0):

If "GT2" in column W defines a "win" and column Y is only to show a value when column W = "GT2" and cells in column Y are to display the percentage of occurrences of "GT2" in column W versus the total number of rows that contain values, then the formula for Y1 will be:

`=IF(U1="GT2",COUNTIF(U:U,"GT2")/COUNTA(U:U),"")`

This can be filled down to subsequent rows.

Comment: I made an error with my column reference. It is column U which I have shaded Green with the 7 different results that it could be. Then I have shaded column Y Blue and that is the one I want to give a % result.

Comment: I made an error with my column reference. It is column U which I have shaded Green with the 7 different results that it could be. Then I have shaded column Y Blue and that is the one I want to give a % result. So what I ideally want is this Column Y (Blue shaded) to report the winning % of entries on the results in Column U. I can't attached the screenshot or the spreadsheet as I can't see the option and my limited html coding skills aren't helping me here

Comment: @KellyLaFontaine Answer updated.